# Problem running 'cooccur' function in cooccur-package: undefindes columns selected

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, package, undefined

I am trying to run the `cooccur()` function on a binary presence/absence dataframe, but gets the following error:

> r in `[.data.frame`(mat, spp, site_mask[spp, ] * site_mask[spp_next,  :
> undefined columns selected

and I can't figure out what the problem is.

My data looks like:

|  | sp1 | sp2 | sp3 | sp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

and I use the call:

```
library(cooccur)
co <- print(cooccur(data, type="site_spp", spp_names = TRUE))
```

because my input data is a dataframe with species in columns and sites in rows.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to help Astrid, but in case others have this issue - it seems to be a problem with using the "site_spp" option that is not yet fixed in the package code.
You can work around by trasposing your matrix and running it as "spp_site".

So in Astrid's example this should work:

```
library(cooccur)
t.data<-t(data)
co <- print(cooccur(t.data, type="spp_site", spp_names = TRUE))
```